# how to put a var inside a class

Tags: javascript, class, variables, assign

i want to put the value of "max" inside the class along with the other values on the script

this variable:

> var max = $('#qtyA').val();

and put it here:

```
$("[name$='OUTopt']").prop('class','validate[minCheckbox[1],maxCheckbox[]] checkbox text')
```

to be more specific inside of:

> maxCheckbox[]

it should look like this:

> maxCheckbox[max]
>
> $("[name$='OUTopt']").prop('class','validate[minCheckbox[1],maxCheckbox[max]]
>   checkbox text')

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {   

    $("#srv").on('change', function() {
        var max = $('#qtyA').val();
        alert(max);
        var selVal = $(this).val();

        if (selVal == 'Inbound') { // Inbound
            $('.Inbound').show();
            $('.Outbound').hide();
            $("[name$='OUTopt']").prop('class','')
            $("#OUTsrvOtr").prop('class','')

            $("[name$='INopt']").prop('class','validate[minCheckbox[1],maxCheckbox['max']] checkbox text')
            $('#valOUT').val('');
            $('div#Outbound').find('span').prop('class','');

        }
        else if (selVal == 'Outbound') { // Outbound
            $('.Inbound').hide();
            $('.Outbound').show();
            $("[name$='INopt']").prop('class','')
            $("#INsrvOtr").prop('class','')

            $("[name$='OUTopt']").prop('class','validate[minCheckbox[1],maxCheckbox['max']] checkbox text')
                $('#valIN').val('');
            $('div#Inbound').find('span').prop('class','');

        }
        else {
            $('.Inbound').hide();
            $('.Outbound').hide();
            $('#valOUT').val('');
            $('#valIN').val('');
            $("[name$='INopt']").prop('class','')
            $("#OUTsrvOtr").prop('class','')
            $('div#Inbound').find('span').prop('class','');

            $("[name$='OUTopt']").prop('class','')
            $("#OUTsrvOtr").prop('class','')
            $('div#Outbound').find('span').prop('class','');
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Writing `'validate[minCheckbox[1],maxCheckbox[' + max + ']] checkbox text'` won't do what you need? Also, are you sure you don't need to pass actual value of `validate[minCheckbox[1],maxCheckbox[max]` as a string into the class list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `max` variable value to appear in the class, then write:

```
$("[name$='INopt']").addClass('validate[minCheckbox[1],maxCheckbox[' + max + ']] checkbox text');
```

I suppose this complex class name is intended for some jQuery validation plugin.